# Comparing Stack value to String in java

Tags: java, comparison, stack, boolean

I am trying the following code:

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Stack s=new Stack();
    s.push(5-4);
    s.push(9);
    s.push(51);
    if(s.get(1).equals("9"))
        System.out.println("yes its comparable");
    System.out.println(s.get(1));

 }
}
```

The actual output is:

```
9
```

I expect the output to be:

```
yes its comparable
9
```

I am unable to figure it out. I have tried s.get(1)=="9" also but it doesn't work too. What might be key behind this? Are they both not strings? or one is string one is object but still they are comparable. Can anybody enlighten me on this?

Comment: They are comparable, but different type of object (Integer and String)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`9` is an integer. `"9"` is a string.

```
s.get(1).equals("9"); // false
s.get(1).equals(9); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

`9` is an `Integer` and `"9"` is a `String`.

Therefore they are not equal.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing 2 different types - `String` and `Integer`. Using a reference type in `Stack` can prevent this confusion

```
Stack<Integer> s=new Stack<Integer>();
```

Using the raw type

```
Stack s=new Stack();
```

causes Object types to be used so that for example when

```
s.push(5-4);
```

is invoked, it is autoboxed into an `Integer` type. Then the expression

```
s.get(1).equals("9"))
```

evaluates to `false` as the `equals` method checks the type before doing the comparison

```
if (obj instanceof Integer) {
   return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  if(s.get(1).equals("9"))
  System.out.println("yes its comparable");  //This prints when if condition datisfied
  System.out.println(s.get(1)); // This is run always
```

make sure use parenthesis

```
 if(condition){
    // if satisfied condition execute this 

   }
```

I think bellow code you are expecting

```
    if(s.get(1).equals(9)) // use int value not String 
        {
            System.out.println("yes its comparable");
            System.out.println(s.get(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

9(integer) in stack and "9" (String) aren't equal. 
To compare them use:

```
s.get(1).toString().equals("9")
```

**OR**

```
s.get(1).equals(Integer.parseInt("9"))
```